# Visual Studio перестал показывать значения переменных при отладке

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Почему-то в режиме отладки перестали отображаться значения переменных, если добавить вручную в "Контрольные значения" пишет ошибки вида:

> "error CS0012: Тип "IEnumerator<>" определен в сборке, на которую нет
>   ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=     "

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

*Сервис - Параметры - Отладка - Общие - поставить галочку "Использовать устаревшие вычислители выражений C# и VB"*